# WPF - how to know when all Images in a FlowDocument have been downloaded

Tags: wpf, bitmapimage, flowdocument

My scenario: using the MVVM pattern I'm marrying a XAML `FlowDocument` with a ViewModel, *not* displaying it on the UI, but converting it to an XPS file.

This mostly works: everything gets rendered properly, including `Image`'s that have an HTTP URL but are relatively small or have already been displayed on the UI (and are therefore cached). The only `gotcha` is images that are large-ish and take 1-2 seconds to fully download. These are not included in the final file output; no big surprise here. But I need a way to guarantee that the XPS output will include *all* images, regardless of size or whether they've been cached or not.

**Idea #1:**

Have some sort of inspection mechanism on the FlowDocument that can find all images and determine if they are in fact downloaded/ready, then when all are good, run the XPS conversion

The problem here is there is even if I were to create some elaborate document inspector, it's not like the `Image` control has any property indicating it is fully loaded.

**Idea #2** 
Eagerly load all images that I know will be included in the FlowDocument. Once they are in the mysterious WPF image cache, in theory there should be no issue rendering even very large images in the XPS file.

I got pretty far into this approach, and almost got it to work. My issue is that I can't find a reliable way to forego the eager downloading if the image is already cached; there doesn't seem to be a way to test for it being in the cache. Checking the `IsDownloading` property of BitmapImage doesn't appear to be reliable, as it often will return `true` even if a given image is already cached.

**The ideal solution**
would be #1, and setup as an `async Task` that a client can `await` until all the images in the FlowDocument are fully realized.

Comment: When a BitmapImage's `IsDownloading` property returns true, always attach a `DownloadCompleted` handler and wait until it's called to mark the image as complete. If the image was cached, the handler is called immediately. And of course also handle the `DownloadFailed` event.

Comment: I experimented with that, and found that if the image is already cached, the `Downloadcompleted` handler is never called. Is there a magic step in the `BitmapImage`'s initialization process in which the handler must be attached?

Comment: Sure that IsDownloading was true when the DownloadCompleted handler isn't called? You should probably always attach a handler before calling EndInit().